# NUMA systems, virtual pages, and false sharing

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, numa

As I understand things, for perfromance on NUMA systems, there are two cases to avoid:

1. threads in the same socket writing to the same cache line (usually 64 bytes)
2. threads from different sockets writing to the same virtual page (usually 4096 bytes)

A simple example will help. Let's assume I have a two socket sytem and each socket has a CPU with two physical cores (and two logical cores i.e. no Intel hyper-threading or AMD two cores per module).  Let me borrow the digram at [OpenMP: for schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850155/openmp-for-schedule/10852852#10852852)

```
| socket 0    | core 0 | thread 0 |
|             | core 1 | thread 1 |

| socket 1    | core 2 | thread 2 |
|             | core 3 | thread 3 |
```

So based on case 1 it's best to avoid e.g. thread 0 and thread 1 writing to the same cache line and based on case 2 it's best to avoid e.g. thread 0 writing to the same virtual page as thread 2.

However, I have been informed that on modern processors that the second case is no longer a concern.  Threads between sockets can write to the same virtual page efficiently (as long as they don't write to the same cache line).

**Is case two no longer a problem? And if it is still a problem what's the correct terminology for this?  Is is correct to call both cases a kind of false sharing?**

Comment: What's your source for "I have been informed"?

Comment: @timday, it's in the comments here.  I don't have a NUMA system.  I only know what I read and from what I have read case 2 still applies but now I don't know.

Comment: opps...I mean in the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741802/why-would-parallelization-decrease-performance-so-dramatically/21748825#21748825

Answer (score 2):

You're right about case 1.  Some more details about case 2:

Based on the operating system's [NUMA policy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/get_mempolicy.2.html) and any related [migration issues](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/unexpected-linux-memory-migration/), the physical location of the page that threads 0 and 2 are writing to could be socket 0 or socket 1.  The cases are symmetrical so let's say that there's a [first touch policy](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0650/SGI_Developer/books/OrOn2_PfTune/sgi_html/ch02.html#LE23571-PARENT) and that thread 0 gets there first.  The sequence of operations could be:

1. Thread 0 allocates the page.
2. Thread 0 does a write to the cache line it'll be working on.  That cache line [transitions from invalid to modified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) within cache(s) on socket 0.
3. Thread 2 does a write to the cache line it'll be working on.  To put that line in exclusive state, socket 1 has to send a Read For Ownership to socket 0 and receive a response.
4. Threads 0 and 2 can go about their business.  As long as thread 0 doesn't touch thread 2's cache line or vice versa and nobody else does anything that would change the state of either line, all operations that thread 0 and thread 2 are doing are socket- (and possibly core-) local.

You could swap the order of 2. and 3. without affecting the outcome.  Either way, the round trip between sockets in step 3 is going to take longer than the socket-local access in step 2, but that cost is only incurred once for each time thread 2 needs to put its line into a modified state.  If execution continues for long enough in between transitions in the state of that cache line, the extra cost will amortize.